# Unity2D - GUI not showing up

Tags: c#, scripting, unity-game-engine

Alright, so I'm currently having a problem with the GUI's in Unity. I cannot figure out how to get this GUI to show up. Its attached to a gameObject that's oriented on the Player character but won't actually appear on the camera.

Here's the kicker though, the same thing works on another gameObject; the only difference being that its triggered by walking through a box collider.

Here's the code:

```
    void OnGui()
{
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(20,70,80,20), "Here's a button")) {

        //Do stuff.
    }
}
```

Pretty simple enough right? In theory it should pop up onto the screen...

Comment: Is it a layering issue?

Comment: @RickS It shouldn't be, it has no background to block the view of it.

Comment: Are you sure this code is getting called? i.e. put a breakpoint and debug it.

Comment: @RickS Hm, no it wasn't actually being called. (A silly mistake on my part not actually checking that.) I should be able to figure out the rest now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call OnGUI() and not OnGui() otherwise Unity will not recognize the method.

Comment: *Facepalm* Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't actually attempt to debug it prior to asking this question. Turns out onGUI wasn't being called.